# LinQ to Entities: Lambda where

Tags: linq, lambda, entity

I have met a weird situation.
When I tried to search items with lambda,

```
searchGuid = new Guid(condition[0]);
searchItem = searchItem.Where(x => x.SiteId == searchGuid);
searchGuid = new Guid(condition[1]);
searchItem = searchItem.Where(x => x.FunctionTypeId == searchGuid);
```

It returns nothing.
But when I change to

```
searchGuid = new Guid(condition[0]);
searchGuid2 = new Guid(condition[1]);
searchItem = searchItem.Where(x => x.SiteId == searchGuid && 
                                   x.FunctionTypeId == searchGuid2);
```

It returns right item which I expected.

Btw, it works with Linq to sql.

Thanks.

Comment: It is due to deferred execution. In the first example where in 2nd line is actually executed after 4th line. So 2 searchGuid are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda functions *capture* the `searchGuid` variable, so at the time you execute your query, `searchGuid` is `new Guid(condition[1])`, hence your query is equivalent to

```
searchItem.Where(x => x.SiteId == new Guid(condition[1]))
          .Where(x => x.FunctionTypeId == new Guid(condition[1]))
```

which is not what you want.

You found a solution by yourself: Use a second variable (or just inline it).